# Spring MVC on GAE: Slow Load Time

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I recently deployed a Spring MVC application to google app engine, and the intial load time is about 7sec. Once the application is loaded, the app is quite responsive. But, if the app is idle for more than 1 minute (there isn't ANY traffic to it) the app needs to be again reloaded by GAE, which, takes about 7sec as well. For a PRD-level application this is unacceptable. (*The app is empty -- I'm not even using JPA, Sitemesh, Spring Security, etc yet. It just loads a jsp page with some text.*)

The only "best practice" to fix the 'load time' I've seen so far is to set up a cron job that hits the url every minute, therefore keeping the app 'loaded'. Obviously this is a terrible solution.

***So here is the question: Are there any "best practices" for Spring on GAE in terms of "responsiveness"? Since google and spring are working on developing better integration between the two of them, has there been any news/progress on this problem? I can't find anything concrete, that's why I'm asking it here***

Topic Discussions: 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/80d014fd5abd526f

**UPDATE**

There is a 'ticket' to create reserved instances, as well as 'heat up' logic:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2456

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the cron job "obviously" a bad solution.  It "obviously" grates, but if it works...

Comment: As the application grows, the amount of time it takes for it to initialize will increase, therefore the 1 minute cron job will turn into a 30sec cron job if the app takes 30 seconds to initialize, etc. Just adding spring security would increase the load time quite drastically. Also, it adds unnecessary complexity for a Spring/GAE problem that should be fixed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE started to provide a paid-for service where you can have a hot instance reserved at all times:

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/12/happy-holidays-from-app-engine-team-140.html

> Always On - For high-priority applications with low or variable traffic, you can now reserve instances via App Engine's Always On feature. Always On is a premium feature costing $9 per month which reserves three instances of your application, never turning them off, even if the application has no traffic. This mitigates the impact of loading requests on applications that have small or variable amounts of traffic.

In conjunction with warm-up requests, this is the best solution if you're planning on using GAE.

Answer (score 2):

Since [SDK 1.4.0](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/12/happy-holidays-from-app-engine-team-140.html) you can avoid this latency using [warmup requests](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Warmup_Requests).
Warmup requests load application code into a new instance before any live requests reach that instance.

Comment: This works only once the initial instance is loaded (which takes more than 10 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, due to lack of responses I decided to go with the cron job (since I can't see any other option as of now)

Here is the cron.xml file I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/keepalive</url>
    <description>Keep the application alive</description>
    <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

And here's the controller:

```
package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.web;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/keepalive")
public class KeepAliveController {

    private Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeepAliveController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void keepAlive() {
        logger.info("I'm alive!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this.  http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#Should_I_Run_A_Cron_Job

Comment: I've read that, unfortunately there is NO OTHER WAY! Unless I want my users to wait for 10seconds before my page loads, this is the ONLY way to keep it relatively "production-ready". As I mentioned above, Google is working on a solution (both paid and free). Until this solution is created, a lot of people who created java applications to be deployed on google are out of luck: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2456

Comment: If your "production" application has some SLA (service level agreement) requirements, then you need to consider better hosting solutions than GAE. GAE does not guarantee uptime, response times, etc. and especially not for the free accounts. If you want to use GAE, then your users are gonna have to pay the wait time. However, if you need some kind of reliability, then you will probably looking at spending a few bucks.

Comment: @Gweebz -- There was no mention (or warning) on GAE's site that the load time for a Java application might exceed 15 seconds, and to make a quick switch from one "platform" to another (e.g. amazon) isn't feasible in most cases. So those people that decided to developer their java app on GAE weren't aware of this huge stumbling block. Also, when I started this "thread", there wasn't an option to pay for a "always-on" instance.